# Handle a pdf response from API in Django

Tags: django, pdf, python-requests

I would like to know how I can display a pdf in my template. I'm using the python library **requests** to get the response from an external API. In the get request the API sends me a pdf, but I do not know how to handle it to show it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf can be returned to the template from the view using HttpResponse object by setting the content type as shown in the code snippet below:

```
def pdf_response(request):
   html_template="Your template path"

   #sending the PDF back as response
   response=HttpResponse(pdf_file,content_type='application/pdf')
   response['Content-Disposition']='filename="test.pdf"'
   return response
```

Than define the corresponding URL in the urls.py file

`url(r'^pdf/$',views.pdf_response, name='pdf'),`

Than in your template define something like this:

`PDF Details</h1><a href="{% url 'pdf' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>`

Comment: The problem is that the pdf viewer shows me the warning that the document might not be displayed correctly. My question is, if I do not have the pdf as a file, but the response of the request to the api returns me that pdf ... how would I do it?

Comment: Just before you build up the response, fetch the pdf file and save it to your media folder and then send it back as a response.